# Align items to either left or right

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm writing chat application, and I want to align messages to either left or right, just like in Messenger or any other similar application.

Parent container looks like this

```
<div class="middle-box border-top border-bottom" #chatContainer>
    <app-message *ngFor="let message of messages" [message]="message" [userMessage]="isUserMessage(message)"></app-message>
</div>

.middle-box {
  min-height: 550px;
  max-height: 550px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And then inside `app-message` I have

```
<div *ngIf="userMessage" class="row no-gutters user-message-box">
    <div class="user-message">
        {{message.messagePayload}}
    </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="!userMessage" class="row no-gutters message-box">
    <div class="message">
        {{message.messagePayload}}
    </div>
</div>


.user-message {
    min-width: 60px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
.message {
    min-width: 60px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #0a4172;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}

.user-message-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

.message-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

But for some reason, everything is aligned to left, and I can't figure out why.
[image]

Comment: Try to use `float` `left` and `right`.
Maybe it will help.

Comment: It did not, in fact messages are displaying in row now.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz about it.
Because you need to separate the classes of messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
.user-message-box {
  display: flex;
}

.message-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Worked exactly as I wanted.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.user-message-box {
  display: flex;
 float: left;
width: 100%;
}

.message-box {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}
```